# symfony change url of object action

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, admin-generator

I have an object action `approve` and I'd like to change its url from `/module/ListApprove/action?id=XXX` to `/module/:slug/approve`. I have tried adding a route in `routing.yml` but no help. Also, I have `ecexuteApprove` defined in my action.

modified `routing.yml`:

```
poster_approve:
  url: /poster/:slug/approve
  params: {module: poster, action: approve}

poster:
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    model:                Poster
    module:               poster
    prefix_path:          /poster
    column:               slug
    with_wildcard_routes: true
```

when I manually call `/poster/someslug/approve`, it works fine. But in the admin list interface, in the actions column, the url for approve is not `/poster/someslug/approve` , instead it is `/poster/ListApprove/action?id=12`.

After it I added an action parameter to my `generator.yml` like this:

```
        object_actions:    
          _delete: 
            credentials: delete_poster
          approve:            
            credentials: approve_poster
            action:      approve
```

but the only change this time is, the link url becomes `/poster/approve/action?id=12`. How do I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does your routing.yml action look like? You could add something like:

```
list_approve:
  url:    /someModule/:slug/:id
  param:  { module: someModule, action: approve }
```

Please define **but no help**, what problem are you encountering?